# I moved my mvc views to a new folder and my application sdoesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, directory

I moved my views from folder Views to Views/Managers and, off course, now it's like they don't exist.
Where can I change the path to the views?? Can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify which view will be used for rendering in the appropriate ActionResult in your Controller.

The line that says:

```
retun View(model);
```

Just use another overload:

```
return View("/Views/Managers/[name of the view]", model)
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify the view when you return it from your action method.

When the view is named like your action and is in the right folder, its enough to say

```
return View();
```

Otherwise you can specify the location:

```
return View("MySubFolder/MyView");
```